# asp.net mvc web api redirect to restful url after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ember.js

I am using Asp.net MVC API with emberjs. I need to redirect the user to a restful path after the user is authenticated. I am using simplemembershiprovider. Here is what the ember template created for me for login controller. I tried assigning the returnURL value but if I do that, the page stays at the login page even though user has been authenticated.

```
if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
{
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
     var redURL = @"http://localhost:20592/#/newlead";
     returnUrl = @"http://localhost:20592/#/newlead";
     return Json(new { success = true, redirect = returnUrl });
}
```

So how does one do restful page redirect with web API?

This is the _login.cshtml

```
@model BeastMVC.Models.LoginModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("JsonLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log in Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { autofocus = "autofocus", id = "loginName" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
            </li>
        </ol>
        @Html.ValidationSummary() 
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Will you show your client side code that calls the login api controller?  This is the correct idea btw, is the json going back to the client?

Comment: This is copied directly from _login.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Web Api doesn't redirect the browser through ajax calls, it can send back data that can be used by client side logic to redirect.  In your case i think you just want to do `Response.Redirect(redURL);`

Comment: I tried to do that but when there is a redirect URL, it does not reach HomeController for some reason, which is the place I am starting my ember framework. If redirect URL is null, then it does get there. Also, I set redirect URL to an outside, none restful link, like www.google.com then it works fine and redirects me to that page.